# "Insufficient storage" while updating

Tags: clash-of-clans, android

I can't update Clash of Clans from Google Play. It says "insufficient storage" even though plenty of storage is available. What should I do?

Comment: Open more space. If it is 100mbs, you need 500mbs as it'll download and install it. After installing it, there should be 300mb-like left space.

Comment: Use cache clearing apps (like CCleaner). Works for me every time.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same trouble. Uninstalling then restalling it worked for me.

Comment: Can confirm this.  The APK (Android application package) is a compressed format, so the download size does not reflect the actual size of the program.  When the download is complete, the package will need room to expand and (in the case of an upgrade) needs room to compare and update files as needed.  Uninstalling/reinstalling means that you'll get back the full amount of space open needed to expand the game.